# How to send a file with NodeJS and express.router?

Tags: node.js, express

I'm trying to send a file from nodeJS and express.router to a client. But i get this error:

> ...webserver/node_modules/express/lib/response.js:412
>       if (done) return done(err);
>                        ^
>
> TypeError: done is not a function
>       at /home/alex/project/webserver/node_modules/express/lib/response.js:412:22
>       at SendStream.ondirectory (/home/pthong/project/webserver/node_modules/express/lib/response.js:986:5)
>       at emitNone (events.js:67:13)
>       at SendStream.emit (events.js:166:7)
>       at SendStream.redirect (/home/alex/project/webserver/node_modules/express/node_modules/send/index.js:401:10)
>       at onstat (/home/alex/project/webserver/node_modules/express/node_modules/send/index.js:622:41)
>       at FSReqWrap.oncomplete (fs.js:82:15)

And this is my code:

```
router.get('/getFile/:filename', function(req,res){
    res.sendFile(__dirname, '../uploads', req.params.filename);
});
```

And the http request is:
http://dummy.com/getFile/audio-461074839300.3gpp

--
and if I try this:

```
res.sendFile('/uploads/'+ req.params.filename);
```

I get the next error:

> Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, stat
>   '/uploads/audiomessage-10207974875988003-1327917607235274-1461074839300.3gpp'
>       at Error (native)

this is the structure of the webserver:
webs

- Webserver
- ---server.js
- ---uploads
- -----audio-461074839300.3gpp
- -----audio-234.3gpp

Comment: Read the documentation for `sendFile`.  Your parameters are wrong.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try res.sendFile(__dirname + filepath/filename)

In your case, this might be:

```
res.sendFile(__dirname + "/uploads/" + req.params.filename);
```